# How can i configure portable mariadb server to run directly in my standalone php desktop application without having to install or use Windows service

Tags: php, mysql, mariadb

I developed a retail management php desktop application using php/mysql that works fine on localhost. But when i converted it into a standalone php desktop application, the app could not connect to the portable mariadb server.

How can i embed the portable mariadb server so that it can run directly without having to be installed on my client's laptop or use a Windows service?
I receive HY000/1049: Unknown database error message.

Please i need your help and thanks in advance.

Comment: look at mysql_embedded

Comment: Hello Bernd, what i realy want is an embedded version of phpdesktop chrome with mysql embedded into it and instead of phpmyadmin i will like to use adminer.php. So my problem is how to include a portable Mysql server (MariaDB) with my standalone php application and start/stop it automatically when the application is started or stopped.

Comment: take a look a kiosk software. you can start stop etc. every thing. https://www.capterra.com/sem-compare/kiosk-software/?utm_source=ps-google&utm_medium=ppc&gclid=CjwKCAjwrZOXBhACEiwA0EoRD-NqErb293xsysWMYzKVGZATxGHbITEthGB-VYhjrOgd3yFDcMtPjxoC8E0QAvD_BwE

Comment: What i mean is php desktop chrome application and not mobile application